# Java Form Generator

Tags: java

Can anybody help me with the code for generaing a Form dynamciall whenever a WSDL url is specified..

Comment: For what purpose do you need the form?

Comment: What have WSDL in common with Form ?

Answer (score 1):

interesting idea. You want to create an application where the user can load a WSDL and the application pops up a screen that allows the user to access the underlying webservice?
You do realise that a single WSDL can contain many calls?

It can certainly be done, but it's far from trivial and certainly not something someone's just going to give you "the code" for.

Answer (score 1):

you could try these links

- [form.io](https://form.io/#/)
  A Form and Data Management Platform for
  Serverless Form-based Applications

Simplify the connections between your forms and APIs.
Integrate with 3rd party providers and legacy systems.
All while maintaining control of your data.

- [jotform.com](https://www.jotform.com/)
  Easy-to-use online form builder for everyone.
- [reinra/dynaform](https://github.com/reinra/dynaform)
  A dynamic schema-based web form generator in Java